# Exception is thrown delayed

Tags: python, exception

I have the following script in Python:

```
import sys


for filename in sys.argv:
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        print("Foobar")
```

If I start the script with a nonexisting filename as a parameter, I get an exception, as expected. However, the `print()` is still executed, even though I expect that it isn't.

```
Foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/bin/ksp-increment-build", line 16, in <module>
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'asdads'
```

Why is this?

Comment: `if len(sys.argv) > 1 : for file in (sys.argv[1:]): if file  in str(os.walk()):`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first element of `sys.argv` is the path to the script being run itself, so it can be opened properly.

The second element would be the nonexisting filename, which throws the error before the print function.